# how to send the %-sign with System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait

Tags: c#, sendkeys

for SendKeys the %-sign is the code for the Alt-key.
But I did'nt find a way to send a pure %-sign.
The following console-application-program shows it.
You have to start the notepad.exe before.
Then you see in Notepad only "percent-sign=" without the %.
After keypressing the program sends "%B" to notepad
It opens on a german system the Edit-Menu (Alt-B --> "Bearbeiten" = "Edit").
The msdn-help explain the function of the + ^and % sign, but not what I've to do to send this signs pure.
Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SendTextToNotepadSendKeys
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindow(
            string lpClassName, // class name     
            string lpWindowName // window name 
            );

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(
            int hWnd // handle to window
            );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At least one instance of notepad must be running! if ready press a key!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            int handleThisWindow = (int)Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            int handleNotepad = FindWindow(null, "Unbenannt - Editor"); // change to your windows title - this is the german one
            if (handleNotepad == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("notepad window not found - possibly you have to change the window title in program code! Please press a key!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                // >>>>>>>>>>> here you see it <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                SetForegroundWindow(handleNotepad);
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("percent-sign=%"); // the text ends with "="
                SetForegroundWindow(handleThisWindow);

                Console.WriteLine("the text in notepad ends with '='");
                Console.WriteLine("% is representing the Alt-key, we show it with the following code");
                Console.WriteLine("on german machines Alt-B will open the Edit-menu - possibly change 'B' in the code for your machine");
                Console.ReadKey();

                SetForegroundWindow(handleNotepad);
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%B");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To send a literal `%`, enclose it in curly braces: `{%}`.

[More information from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks)

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}". To specify brace characters, use "{{}" and "{}}". Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys, but you must enclose them in braces. In other applications, brackets do have a special meaning that might be significant when dynamic data exchange (DDE) occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I used this function for VBS, it's easy enough to understand what it's doing, just port to your preferred language.... Call with your text string, i.e. for VBS:

`strText = "My%Text~With+Escape^Chars"`

`strText = EscapeChars(strText)`

You will get a return string with brackets around the `%, ~, +,` and `^` that works perfect in SendKeys, i.e. `"My{%}Text{~}With{+}Escape{^}Chars"`

```
Function EscapeChars(vStr)
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 to Len(vStr)
        If Grep("[%()~!+^]", Mid(vStr, i, 1)) Then
            EscapeChars = EscapeChars & "{" & Mid(vStr, i, 1) & "}"
        Else
            EscapeChars = EscapeChars & Mid(vStr, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob this was the only why it worked out, I have tested with:
%
)
(
Witch is the most likly to happen.

I had to modefy your code the `GREP` part didn't work for me so I did this insted:

```
    Function EscapeChars(vStr)
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 to Len(vStr)
        If "%" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "+" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "^" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "!" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "(" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or ")" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "[" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "]" = Mid(vStr, i, 1)_
           Or "~" = Mid(vStr, i, 1) Then
            EscapeChars = EscapeChars & "{" & Mid(vStr, i, 1) & "}"
        Else
            EscapeChars = EscapeChars & Mid(vStr, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    End Function
```

I basicly only had to put a lot of `Or` statements in and it worked like a charm, thanks.